# Adding Bluetooth to an old Mac Pro that doesn't have it

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth

I want to hook up a Magic Mouse and Wireless Keyboard to an older Mac Pro (cheese grater) that doesn't come equppied with Bluetooth.  I see that there are various usb dongles that you can purchase that seemingly add bluetooth and some of them say they are Mac compatible but I am wondering if anyone has any experience with doing this and can point me to one they know for a fact works.

Thanks!

Comment: 'Shopping recommendations' are off topic here, I'm afraid, but your choices depend on exactly which Mac Pro you have. Even the 5,1 is hard to get Handoff to work. Earlier machines can't use BT LE 4.0.. https://www.imore.com/how-add-handoff-capabilities-your-older-mac-pro has a guide. The actual hardware fit is 'not the easiest, but not *really* tough'. their guide looks like they are dealing with a 4,1

Comment: @Tetsujin - Apologies I didn't realize that that was off topic (but fair enough).  For what it's worth, in case someone has this question in the future, I was only looking to add Bluetooth in order to make a Magic Mouse and Apple Wireless Keyboard work. I found a Mac compatible Bluetooth usb dongle, plugged it in, and it started working immediately with no setup.  Thank you for your help!